# PHP app not communicating with certain MYSQL databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, iis, mysqli

I have a PHP web app which has been working fine until today (it is sitting on an Windows/IIS server). When I attempt to access a page which connects to the MYSQL database, I get a blank page in firefox. In IE I get a 500 Internal Server Error. Normal PHP works fine, it is simply when I try to connect to the database. The mysqli connection is not giving any error messages.

The weird thing - I have phpmyadmin on the same server and it is working fine, I can see my database and interact with it.

I also have another database on the server which is working fine, the user attached to that database has read only access (as it is an archive database), but the PHP web app connecting to it works.

**What have I tried?**

- Initially I thought it was a user issue, so I created a new user in phpmyadmin with full privileges and had the PHP app log on using it instead, same result.
- I then thought that it was an issue with the database, so I copied the data and structure to a new database, same result.
- The MYSQL.err log file has no errors and indicates that the server is accepting connections (which it is, as phpmyadmin is working).

I have even tried writing a test script:

```
<?php
//Debugging
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

include "settings.php";

echo $HOST . "<br>";
echo $DBNAME . "<br>";
echo $DBUSERNAME . "<br>";
echo $DBPASSWORD . "<br>";

$CON = new mysqli($HOST, $DBUSERNAME, $DBPASSWORD, $DBNAME);

//Check the connection and report error if it failed
if ($CON->connect_errnum > 0)
{
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $CON->connect_error . ']');
}

$result = $CON->query("select user() AS us");

if (!$result)
        die("There was an error running the query [" .$CON->error ."]");
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo $row["us"] . "<br>";
}
?>
```

If I don't have he code from the `$result = $CON->query("select user() AS us");` down, it displays the 4 values. Once I include it, I get the 500 Internal server error page.

I am at a loss to figure out what is happening or where to start looking.

Comment: I feel silly, but I identified my error. One of my support classes had a syntax error in it, this caused the page to fail before it got to the database connection. Because my error reporting was turned off, I could not see this (even though I thought it was on). I had to go in to PHP.ini and set display_errors = off to display_errors = on. This then showed the error message.

Answer (score 0):

One of my support classes had a syntax error in it, this caused the page to fail before it got to the database connection. Because my error reporting was turned off, I could not see this (even though I thought it was on). I had to go in to PHP.ini and set display_errors = off to display_errors = on. This then showed the error message.